# git fetch upstream master not working, what is going wrong?

Tags: bash, git, github, version-control, git-bash

[image]

So I'm wondering if there is a problem with the upstream master? 
I'm not sure if this error happens when everything is updated already or if it's something different.

I have added upstream link with no problem, using 
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/udacity/course-collboration-travel-plans.git

just want to sync with the master now

Comment: `git remote add <name> <url>` does not probe to see if there is a server at `<url>` that can access a Git repository. Are you sure your `<url>` is correct? (Hint: what happens if you click on the URL in your question?)

Answer (score 4):

Of course, your Repository URL: https://github.com/udacity/course-collboration-travel-plans.git is giving 404. There is no repository at your added remote.

Particularly I am seeing a typo  in your remote URL `collboration` ==> `collaboration`. So, correct URL that should be added as a remote is:
https://github.com/udacity/course-collaboration-travel-plans.git

```
# Remove previously incorrect remote
$ git remote rm upstream
# Adding correct remote
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/udacity/course-collaboration-travel-plans.git
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: wow thank you for the help everyone, really missed that there.

Comment: please accept this as an answer in your case – Thanks!

Comment: @DianaRamirez If the answer helps you solve the problem, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.